# Overwrite an entire column with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to overwrite an existing column in a spreadsheet with an updated version of the same column.

I can iterate through the column's rows and replace all values individually using a for loop, but I was wondering if there's a smoother way to completely swap the column all at once, without the for loop. It has to be written back to the original spreadsheet, it can't be sent to a new one. Thanks.
example of the working for loop:

```
col = df.columns.get_loc(x) + 1
        for ind in df.index:
            rangerow = ind + 2
            oldval = df[x][ind]
            newval = abs(oldval * y)
            ws.cell(row=rangerow, column=col).value = newval
```

I'm looking for something more like:

```
df['updatedcolumn'] = df[x]*y
```

to update the column in the dataframe and then writing that entire column to the spreadsheet. Thought it would look roughly something like this (which does not work):

```
ws.column(col).value = df['updatedcolumn']
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I don't really have anything to show aside from the working for loop, but I'll add it. I'm trying to find out if the method to overwrite columns exists in this library. I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: There's nothing in the documentation because it isn't possible, you have to go cell by cell.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a more efficient method available.

Comment: It's not a question of efficiency: it **has** to be done like this and writing the necessary loop is two lines at most.